# Adding IP whitelisting security to API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a API on AWS API gateway which calls LAMBDA function and I want to add IP whitelisting for that API so the allowed IPs only can have access to that API. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really extended blog post about this which you can find [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/aws-api-gateway-ip-restrictions).

Bottom line, it comes to this:

1. Per method, select IAM Authorization method.
2. Create a new IAM policy that looks like the one below and attach it to the API Method.

---

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "xxx.xx.xx.xx/32"
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can add multiple SourceIps if needed.

Comment: You add the IP's to an IAM Policy, then attach the ploicy to your API gateway. That's the only way to do it

Comment: Well, with EC2 you could hack it. Send your users to the ec2 endpoint and run a haproxy/nginx there and only forward requests to your api gateway which match the IP. but the IAM Policy is the preferred way