# API Gateway whitelist certain IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created an AWS API Gateway endpoint which leads to an API that I've created. I want to make this API accessible to certain IPs **without any authentication** (which will access them over the Internet)

This is the policy that I've attached

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123412341234:abcdabcdab/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "141.223.201.10/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The source IP is my IP, from where the endpoint should be accessible. But I'm getting access denied.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227727/adding-ip-whitelisting-security-to-api-gateway) to this but it uses IAM authentication which I don't want.

What am I missing?

Comment: you may need to explicitly specify allow, similar to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-resource-policy-whitelist/)

Comment: I tried that but it isn't working either.

Comment: sooo many things can be going wrong, such as 1 - your IP is incorrect, 2 - your resource reference within the policy is incorrect (which is very plausible based on the looks)

Comment: 1. I checked by looking up my IP and then whitelisted that IP. 2. Can you say what part might be wrong. I'm new to API Gateway Policies.

Comment: if you make "Resource" to be `arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/*/*/*` does it work? If so, then you know it is the Resource in your policy definition...then you can refine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-policy-language-overview.html)?

It does look like that allow is included in the default template too. I went to replicate this and saw that there is a button in the Resource Policy Console "IP Range Blacklist". If you click on it, it will create a policy like this:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard}}",
                "Condition" : {
                    "IpAddress": {
                        "aws:SourceIp": [ "{{sourceIpOrCIDRBlock}}", "{{sourceIpOrCIDRBlock}}" ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard}}"
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can change it from blacklist to whitelist by changing the condition "IpAddress" to the same "NotIpAddress" condition you are using in your non-working template.

This worked for me just fine so if this isn't it, I'd enable [Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html#set-up-access-logging-using-console) on your API GW API and verify the source IP AWS is seeing come in when you make a request (make sure you log the request id too).

To make sure you are looking at the correct access log, when you make the request you should trap the response header "x-amzn-requestid", response header using curl example:

> x-amzn-requestid: 85e403e8-210a-49e4-909e-b3fb66d6467e

FTR, I entered * in the placeholders that the button creates in the default policy and AWS console converted them to the appropriate values so it ends up looking like this after the console conversions. The conversions I'm referring to are the placeholders I have below (REGION, ACCID, APIID):

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:REGION:ACCID:APIID/*/*/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "NotIpAddress": {
                        "aws:SourceIp": "34.213.29.81/32"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:REGION:ACCID:APIID/*/*/*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried it the exact same way but I added `Allow *` on top and that wasn't working. But when I added it to bottom it started working. Also, there seems to be some issue on how many times I can change the policy from API Gateway UI. At first, it works, but later it stops applying new policies.

Comment: Also, is there any way to add range instead of a single IP?

Comment: RE: Range of IP's
Yes, it uses CIDR notation, so the /32 in "aws:SourceIp": "34.213.29.81/32" is for a single IP but you can use a subnet calculator to figure out the /16 or /24 or whatever IP range you need. I use this one: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Comment: RE: Adding it to the bottom
I'm not sure what that's about, it works for me either way! As for the UI applying the policies, are you deploying it after every policy change? You have to deploy the API for policy changes to take effect, and after that it can take a few minutes for the policy changes to populate across the entire API Gateway backend